# regex check valid total characters when input email address

Tags: regex

I need to validate an email address with the following conditions: only lowercase letters, digits, and ._- can be entered. A first letter must be a number or alphabet. Total characters between 10 and 100. This is my regex

```
^((?=[^@]*[a-z])([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9])*([._-])?([a-z0-9]))*@(([a-z0-9-])+(\.))+([a-z]{2,4}+)).{10,100}$
```

But it's not working with `.{10,100}`. I try to use that to check the total characters but it failed. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a lookahead to the start of your pattern asserting that it contains 10 to 100 characters:

```regex
^(?=.{10,100}$)((?=[^@]*[a-z])([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9])*([._-])?([a-z0-9]))*@(([a-z0-9-])+(\.))+([a-z]{2,4}+)).*$
  ^^^ change is here
```